# `set -x` for golang: Print every executed line?

Tags: go, debugging

Is there something like shell feature `set -x` for golang?

I would like to see every line of code which gets executed.

Lines of the standard library should not be printed.

Comment: There is no way doing this, and it would be of very limited use, if existed—with some of the reasons enumerated by Fenistil in their answer. Either use a debugger (most Go-enabled IDEs use `delve`, but it can be used directly, w/o any IDE) or resort to the venerable technique of "hand-made tracing": basically, you insert calls to `fmt.Print*` or `log.Print*` or whatever to key points of your code, interact with your program and try to make out what gets printed. While it looks lame, it's a powerful technique,…

Comment: …and if you have troubles reasoning about the program flow having collected such printouts, this means your code is too convoluted or your programming skills are not yet on par with the complexity of the task (please take no offence—none intended) or both.

Comment: Also note that there exist ways to do "formal" tracing of Go programs: https://pkg.go.dev/runtime/trace for low-level stuff and tools implementing OpenTracing spec (such as Jaeger) to help trace handling of "units of work" (usually client requests) handled by the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine, [using pprof](https://chrisrbailey.medium.com/use-pprof-to-view-go-program-stack-traces-4a97f1286b08):

- [profiling](https://go.dev/blog/pprof), which can help you see who calls what, and for how long

[image: pprof]

([`ofabry/go-callvis`](https://github.com/ofabry/go-callvis) can also help to see a call graph)

- Its Weblist view  which shows each executed line and their cost:

[image: https://storage.googleapis.com/golangorg-assets/pprof-weblist.png]

See "Interactive Profiling" in [this guide](https://ydkgo.netlify.app/docs/profiling).

This won't display each line executed in order, but allows you to explore after a run what was executed.

---

Note that Go 1.20/1.21 (Q4 2022/Q2 2023) will include (since [#55022](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/55022#issuecomment-1269167771) is accepted):

> ### [Profile-Guided Optimization (PGO) for Go](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/changes/97/439297/2/design/55022-pgo-implementation.md)
>
> Inefficiencies in Go programs can be isolated via profiling tools such as `pprof` and linux profiler `perf`. Such tools can pinpoint source code regions where most of the execution time is spent.
>
> Unlike other optimizing compilers such as LLVM, the Go compiler does not yet perform **Profile-Guided Optimization(PGO)**.
> PGO uses information about the code’s runtime behavior to guide compiler optimizations such as inlining, code layout etc. PGO can improve application performance in the range 15-30% [LLVM, AutoFDO].
>
> In this proposal, we extend the Go compiler with PGO.
>
> Specifically, we incorporate the profiles into the frontend of the compiler to build a call graph with node & edge weights (called **`WeightedCallGraph`**). The Inliner subsequently uses the `WeightedCallGraph` to perform profile-guided inlining which aggressively inlines hot functions.
>
> We introduce a profile-guided code specialization pass that is tightly integrated with the Inliner and eliminates indirect method call overheads in hot code paths.
>
> Furthermore, we annotate IR instructions with their associated profile weights and propagate these to the SSA-level in order to facilitate profile-guided basic-block layout optimization to benefit from better instruction-cache and TLB performance.
>
> Finally, we extend Go's linker to also consume the profiles directly and perform function reordering optimization across package boundaries -- which also helps instruction-cache and TLB performance.
>
> The format of the profile file consumed by our PGO is identical to the protobuf format produced by the `pprof` tool. This format is rich enough to carry additional hardware performance counter information such as cache misses, LBR, etc.
> Existing `perf_data_converter` tool from Google can convert a `perf.data` file produced by the Linux `perf` into a `profile.proto` file in protobuf format.

There will be a new compilation flow proposed in Go for PGO

[image: New compilation flow proposed in Go for PGO]

Answer (score 3):

Since Go is a compiled language the executable doesn't contain any original source code, so output would be impossible. The closest you can come to the approach you want is to run your Go project in Debug mode and step through every line of code.

This way you can decide while running to jump into a function or just execute it and jump over it, because the debugger won't know what you consider "standard library" and what should traced line-by-line and what not.

On the other hand, Go can be heavily multi-threaded with go routines, so printing every executed line could be a mess in a minute (sometimes I have more than a houndred routines running the same time).

Comment: «Go can be heavily multi-threaded with go routines, so printing every executed line could be a mess in a minute»—moreover, this makes "step-based" debugging implemented in a typical debuggers helpless in most but the most obvious cases.

Comment: I think that sooner or later someone will write a tool so that works roughly like `set -x`. It is not impossible. It might be slow, but doable.

Comment: @guettli I can only imagine it to analyze the source and generate an alternate one with `fmt.Println` or something inserted after every executable line and around any code struct (like ifs, loops, etc). But I still think it print out a whole mess.

Comment: @guettli: the actual executed machine code may not even align with the source. Debuggers have a hard enough time matching pc to a useful line, but it's going to make even less sense trying to print out some sort of source code in isolation. In the rare cases that people want this, they usually instrument their code (which may be completely machine generated) to log at the granularity desired.

Comment: @guettli, JFTR, the "pc" JimB referred to in his comment is [this thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_counter) ;-)